# Combine color with conditional newlines in git log output

Tags: git, git-log

When I invoke the following command:

```
git log --format=format:"%C(yellow)%h %C(blue)%s %C(green)%ad %C(reset)%an%n%n%-b"
```

I get output that looks like this:

[image]

I would like the commit bodies to be dimmed, so I tried inserting the instruction `%C(dim)` at the end of my format string. However, there does not seem to be an insertion location that achieves my goal:

- Inserting `%C(dim)` after the newlines and before the [(conditional newline-chomping) `%-b` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats) correctly applies the dimming effect, but breaks conditional newline-chomping:

  ```
  git log --format=format:"%C(yellow)%h %C(blue)%s %C(green)%ad %C(reset)%an%n%n%C(dim)%-b"
  ```

  [image]
- Inserting `%C(dim)` before both the newlines and the (conditional newline-chomping) `%-b` command correctly retains conditional newline-chomping, but fails to apply the dimming effect (i.e. no change from original output):

  ```
  git log --format=format:"%C(yellow)%h %C(blue)%s %C(green)%ad %C(reset)%an%C(dim)%n%n%-b"
  ```

  [image]

Additionally, I cannot move the 'chomp' operator `-` to the color command, since that always appears to "evaluate" to a non-empty string (and therefore, newlines are not chomped).

Is there a way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **The final solution (without any known quirks) is at the bottom of
>   this answer**.

A workaround is to put a custom placeholder for the newlines in the format string (without using the `%-b` magic) and then postprocess the output with `sed`. In the example below the placeholder is the **`CHOMPABLENEWLINES`** string (of course you can replace it with any text of your choice, just make sure *that it can't appear in your commit messages*):

```
git log --format=format:"%C(yellow)%h %C(blue)%s %C(green)%ad %C(reset)%an%C(dim)CHOMPABLENEWLINES%b"|sed -e 's/CHOMPABLENEWLINES$//; s/CHOMPABLENEWLINES/\n\n/; $ s/$/\n/'
```

[image: Colored output of git log with sed postprocessing]

Note that this approach also fixes the problem that the effect of the `%C` directive extends only till the end of the current line (at least in git 2.7.4). As a result, in case of a multi-line body the color is applied only to its first line. Compare:

```
# Only the first line of a multiline message body is colored
git log --format=format:"%C(yellow)%h %C(blue)%s %C(green)%ad %C(reset)%an%n%n%Cred%b"
```

[image: Colored output of git log without sed postprocessing]

```
# Entire multiline message body is colored (though a byproduct of this
# is that the color setting persists beyond the current
# command - note the red prompt following the output)
git log --format=format:"%C(yellow)%h %C(blue)%s %C(green)%ad %C(reset)%an%CredCHOMPABLENEWLINES%b"|sed -e 's/CHOMPABLENEWLINES$//; s/CHOMPABLENEWLINES/\n\n/; $ s/$/\n/'
```

[image: Colored output of git log with sed postprocessing]

The undesirable side effect of persisted color setting can be counteracted by ending the format string with a `%C(reset)` directive. Then we also need a custom marker for the end of the `%b` placeholder, since the visual end of line is no longer an actual end of line from `sed`'s point of view. In the example below the string **`ENDOFBODY`** is used as such a marker (and of course you must select it so that it doesn't appear in your expected output).

```
# This version works with GNU sed. For a portable version (including BSD
# and MacOS X systems) scroll down a little more
git log --format=tformat:"%C(yellow)%h %C(blue)%s %C(green)%ad %C(reset)%an%CredCHOMPABLENEWLINES%bENDOFBODY%C(reset)"|sed -e 's/CHOMPABLENEWLINESENDOFBODY//; s/CHOMPABLENEWLINES/\n\n/; s/ENDOFBODY//'
```

[image: Output of the final version]

Some versions or setups of git disable colored output when it doesn't directly go to terminal. In such cases you must also provide the `--color=always` option to `git log`.

---

#### The final solution, using only portable features of sed, is as follows:

```
git log --color=always --format=tformat:"%C(yellow)%h %C(blue)%s %C(green)%ad %C(reset)%an%C(red)CHOMPABLENEWLINES%bENDOFBODY%C(reset)"|sed -e 's/CHOMPABLENEWLINESENDOFBODY//; s/CHOMPABLENEWLINES/\'$'\n''\'$'\n/; s/ENDOFBODY//'
```

Comment: @stkent `--format=tformat:` is similar to `--format=format:` but it adds a newline after the last line of output which helps to slightly shorten the sed script

Comment: @stkent Re formatting. Do you mean that coloring of the output disappears? What OS are you using?

Comment: Yup, all output is white. I'm on macOS 10.13.

Comment: @stkent Can you try to add the `--color=always` option to `git log`? If it gets back the color to the output then I will provide a correct sed command for macOS (which is a little different from Linux).

Comment: Adding `--color=always` brings back the color! There's one final issue I can't figure out; the newlines are printing as literal `n`s. I tried to double escape them but they print as literal `\n`s in that case... :S

Comment: @stkent *the newlines are printing as literal `n`s* That's what I had in mind when I promised to provide a correct sed command for macOS. I updated the answer with a portable version, working identically under Linux and BSD (including macOS) systems.

Comment: Brilliant, looks perfect now. Thanks for your hard work on this!

Comment: @Leon Solid work! Since this uses sed I cannot put this into my git aliases, right?

Comment: @Leon In addition, I presume the sed workaround could be used to address this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34829747/git-log-pretty-format-newline-after-placeholder-if-non-empty

Comment: @angrydust `sed` can be used in aliases indirectly - you must wrap the pipeline in a bash script and refer to it in the alias via the `!` syntax (if the alias expansion is prefixed with an exclamation point, it will be treated as a shell command).

Comment: @angrydust Regarding the other question, for linear histories a sed-based solution most probably exists, but I am not sure if a universal solution handling non-linear histories is at all possible.

Comment: @Leon I see. Sadly that means I won't be able to use this sed workaround to solve q/34829747 :(

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a way to do this without relying on external tools like sed.

The way I would expect it to work, I would just add a newline control plus a color formatter, and both of those would work, like

```
things things %C(yellow)%+d%C(reset)
```

But the yellow color is ignored. However, changing `yellow` to `auto` like this

```
things things %C(auto)%+d%C(reset)
```

applies some color, but it's some set of default colors. You can change those colors in your gitconfig though! So the pretty format won't be 100% portable (like you couldn't inline it into a git command to give to your coworker) but it works in my terminal.

To find the config value to change, I had to do some experimenting. Run `git help -c | grep color` to see a list of colors config values. The ones that colorize `%d` (all the branch names on a given commit) are here:

```
color.decorate.HEAD
color.decorate.branch
color.decorate.grafted
color.decorate.remoteBranch
color.decorate.stash
color.decorate.tag
```

There's probably another similar config value that would dim the commit message like the OP wants. Then you can run `git config --global color.decorate.HEAD yellow` to add this to your gitconfig file:

```
[color "decorate"]
    HEAD = yellow
```

and other config values follow suit.

So ultimately this is what my config ends up like:

```
[format]
    pretty = format:%C(bold cyan)%h%Creset %C(cyan)<%an>%Creset %Cgreen(%cr)%Creset%  %s%C(auto)%+d%C(reset)
[color "decorate"]
    HEAD = yellow
    branch = yellow
    grafted = yellow
    remoteBranch = yellow
    stash = yellow
    tag = yellow
```